# "Error: unterminated parenthesized expression" when using function of object after parenthesis

Tags: syntax-error, crystal-lang

i'm running into the problem:

> Error: unterminated parenthesized expression
> when trying to compile:

```
expiry_epoch = (expiry_date_bytes.pointer(expiry_date_bytes.size) as Int64*).value
```

I'm not that comfortable with crystal so i'm better off asking.

The only fix in my mind is:

```
expiry_epoch = expiry_date_bytes.pointer(expiry_date_bytes.size) as Int64*
expiry_epoch = expiry_epoch.value
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `as` syntax is very old and effectively obsolete by now.

You can write `expiry_date_bytes.pointer(expiry_date_bytes.size).as(Int64*).value`